# The difference between function values for two functions defined by pairs of numbers

Tags: matlab

I have two functions defined by pairs `[x,y]`, where y = f(x). These are the results of two different ode solvers. I can easily plot them, but what I am interested in is the difference between these two. As these come from different solvers, they have different x vectors and lengths. I was wondering if MATLAB has any tool for doing that. It would require some averaging to interpolate the values of f(x) for the x of another function.

Comment: You should provide an example of the data that comes from the functions and what sort of plot you want.

Comment: Sounds like you need to interpolate the one to have the same x vector as the other. Check out `interp1`, it should be straight forward. You'd call it something like: `Yb_interpolated = (Xb, Yb, Xa)` and then you can subtract `Yb_interpolated` from `Ya`

Answer (score 0):

I'd go about it more or less as Dan said. Say your 2 functions are given by `(x1,y1)` and `(x2,y2)`. Unless you want to extrapolate you should look at the intersection between the 2 ranges.

```
a=max(min(x1), min(x2));
b=min(max(x1),max(x2));
CommonX=linspace(a,b,100);
plot(CommonX,interp1(x1,y1,CommonX)-interp1(x2,y2,CommonX))
```